# Posting both checked and unchecked checkboxes

Tags: php, jquery, checkbox, webforms

I'm trying to make a series of checkboxes in a web form that will post either "true" or "false" to the next php page, depending on whether they are checked. I decided that for each checkbox (value="true"), I would have a hidden checkbox (value="false") that would always be the opposite (when checkbox is checked, hidden checkbox is unchecked etc.) I am using jQuery to do this.

The number of 'td' elements is unknown (the 'td' can be cloned an infinite number of times using a button, to submit multiple values). I added the alerts to the jQuery for testing purposes.

When I added the jQuery code and hidden checkbox into my source code (I made it visible for testing purposes), the code wouldn't work AND all the other jQuery on my web page stopped working!

jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    /***post all 'required' checkboxes instead of just checked ones***/
    $(".required").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("test");
        nextIndex = this.index() + 1;
        alert(nextIndex);
        $(".required:eq(nextIndex)").attr("checked", !.required:eq(nextIndex).attr("checked"));
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<td>
    <input type="checkbox" class="required" name="required[]" value="true">
    <input type="checkbox" class="required" name="required[]" value="false" style="display: none;" checked>
</td>
```

Comment: This sounds like a job that is better suited for radio buttons than checkboxes.

Answer (score 9):

You don't have to hide one of the checkboxes.  Here is a solution that should accomplish what you want:

```
<input type="hidden" name="required" value="false" />
<input type="checkbox" name="required" value="true" />
```

If the checkbox is not checked, then the hidden field will be submitted with the `false` value.  If the checkbox is checked, then the `true` value from the checkbox will override the `false` value from the hidden input.

As long as you can name each checkbox something slightly different, it should work.

The following should work as well for an array of values:

```
<input type="hidden" name="required[0]" value="false" />
<input type="checkbox" name="required[0]" value="true" />

<input type="hidden" name="required[n]" value="false" />
<input type="checkbox" name="required[n]" value="true" />
```

This way, you don't need any client side javascript to toggle the hidden checkboxes.

Comment: Yes, the solution is to output a `hidden` element before each checkbox with the checkbox's "off" value. Checking the checkbox causes the "on" value to be posted instead of the hidden input's value.

Comment: This is a good solution, however I don't know how many checkboxes there are going to be... I will see if I can find a way to name them automatically when they are added using the button on my web page.

Comment: As long as you add a hidden input with the same name as the checkbox in the DOM *before* the checkbox element, this should work as long as you have 1 hidden input w/ the same name for each checkbox.  If the hidden input accidentally gets added to the DOM as a node *after* the checkbox, then you will have the reverse effect and the value will always be false (the value of the hidden input).

Comment: Stumbled on this today and had to let you know that this is a brilliant solution. Its so clean and easy to implement!! love learning tricks of the trade like this.

Comment: This is the best solution ive seen so far

Answer (score 1):

This line is probably causing things to break:

```
$(".required:eq(nextIndex)").attr("checked", !.required:eq(nextIndex).attr("checked"));
```

You probably meant:

```
$(".required:eq(" + nextIndex + ")").attr("checked", !$('.required:eq(' + nextIndex + ')').attr("checked"));
```

Also note that you need to take `nextIndex` out of the quotes.

My guess is that your javascript console would have thrown some sort of error related to this.

**EDIT:**

Another error that I noticed was this:

```
nextIndex = this.index() + 1;
```

`.index()` is a jquery function which must be called on a jQuery object. `this` is the element that was clicked, so you will need to say:

```
nextIndex = $(this).index() + 1;
```

BTW, you might want to check out [jQuery's `.next()` function.](http://api.jquery.com/next/) It would save you from all of this `nextIndex` mumbo jumbo.

Comment: Well the other jQuery on my page is working now, so that too care of any syntax errors I had - thanks! However, it still isn't working the way I want it to. When I click the checkbox, I see the first alert message, but not the second, and then the checkbox unchecks itself again. Nothing happens to the hidden checkbox (it remains checked).

Answer (score 0):

If you are naming your checkboxes like this, you don't necessarily have an index to work with:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_name[]" />
```

Then this snippet of jQuery should work for you, assuming that you are OK with relying on javascript.

```
$('form').submit(function(){

    $(":checkbox:not(:checked)").each(function(element, index){
        $(this).attr({value: 'false', checked:'checked'});
    });

    return true;
});
```

This loops through all of the unchecked checkboxes, checks them, and sets their value to `false`. Here is what you get in PHP:

```
[checkbox_name] => Array
    (
        [0] => off
        [1] => on
        [2] => off
    )
```

Instead of:

```
[checkbox_name] => Array
    (
        [0] => on
    )
```